# How to filter the payload response in ruby by converting key and value pair

Tags: ruby, json

Below is a payload response as a string assigned to `string`, and it needs to be converted into a hash.

```
{"method_name":"My function","success":true,"payload":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Elu","Properties":{"TVset":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::VirtualArea","Properties":{"vad_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":"0001"},"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":false,"Value":true}},"Children":{"Music":{"Type":"SM::Mod::Base","Properties":{"reg_id":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"buffer_value":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":10},"special_handling_table":{"Type":"SM::Mod::SpecialHandlingTable","Properties":{"behaviors_val":{"Type":"Hash","Mutable":false,"Value":{"1":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Replace","Properties":{"direct":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::Behavior","Properties":{"direct_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"2":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSH","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"3":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"4":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderres","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"ToTransport"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"5":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Tosnmp"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"6":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSHBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromconn"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"7":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"8":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"9":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null}},"IsActiveChange":null}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"number":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":false,"Value":0,"IsActiveChange":false},"connections":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"threads":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":4},"updates":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"severity":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"levelval":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"facility":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"trace":{"Type":"smode::Depval::Fallback","Properties":{"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":false},"depend":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":""}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}],"error":""}
```

I need to create key and value pairs by parsing:

```
vad_val => "001" , enabled => true , req_id => NULL, buffer_value =>10
```

etc. until end. I need to capture all elements of string, fixnum, and TrueClass as a hash with key and value pair.

I can understand that below code:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(string) # it returns a hash
p parsed["properties"]["someKey"]=value
```

can convert the string into a hash, but I am not sure how this kind of filtering can be done. It needs to proceed further through JSON to retrieve the hash, but it will store all other unwanted information. How can I perform filtering to get somekey as a key (vad_val) and value (0001) and etc? I will appreciate your help regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to iterate through the JSON that's created from the raw data and for each nested (key / hash) where the hash has a "Type" key of "String", "TrueClass", or "Fixnum" you want to produce an output key / value consisting of the key and the value of the "Value" key in the hash.

This should do that. It recursively examines all sub-hashes and arrays in the original JSON structure looking for the above match.

```
raw_data = '{"method_name":"My function","success":true,"payload":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Elu","Properties":{"TVset":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::VirtualArea","Properties":{"vad_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":"0001"},"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":false,"Value":true}},"Children":{"Music":{"Type":"SM::Mod::Base","Properties":{"reg_id":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"buffer_value":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":10},"special_handling_table":{"Type":"SM::Mod::SpecialHandlingTable","Properties":{"behaviors_val":{"Type":"Hash","Mutable":false,"Value":{"1":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Replace","Properties":{"direct":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::Behavior","Properties":{"direct_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"2":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSH","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"3":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"4":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderres","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"ToTransport"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"5":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Tosnmp"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"6":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSHBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromconn"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"7":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"8":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"9":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null}},"IsActiveChange":null}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"number":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":false,"Value":0,"IsActiveChange":false},"connections":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"threads":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":4},"updates":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"severity":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"levelval":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"facility":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"trace":{"Type":"smode::Depval::Fallback","Properties":{"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":false},"depend":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":""}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}],"error":""}'
require 'json'

def breakdown(set, result = {})
  if set.class == Hash # iterate through hash
    set.each do |k, v|
      if v.class == Hash && %w(String TrueClass Fixnum).include?((v["Type"] || ''))
        result[k.to_sym] = v["Value"] # add this key's value to the output array
      elsif v.class == Hash || v.class == Array
        result = breakdown(v, result) # check nested arrays and hashes
      end
    end
  elsif set.class == Array
    set.each do |a|
      result = breakdown(a, result) # check elements of an array
    end
  end
  result
end

broken_down = breakdown(JSON.parse(raw_data))
p broken_down
#> {:vad_val =>"0001", :enabled =>false, :reg_id =>nil, :buffer_value =>10, :direct =>"From", :direct_val =>"From", :decision =>"From", :number =>0, :connections =>nil, :threads =>4, :updates =>nil, :severity =>3, :levelval =>3, :facility =>3, :depend =>""}
```

EDIT
Modified the above to ensure that keys are symbols instead of strings (to match required output)

Comment: Thanks steve  for this solution.

Comment: I can see your changes for string TrueClass and FIxnum only. Have you updated for symbol as well ?

Comment: No, none of the data in the original string were Symbol objects.  What I meant was that instead of producing `"vad_val" => "001"` I changed it to produce `:vad_val => "001"`.  The change I made was to replace `result[k] = v["Value"]` with `result[k.to_sym] = v["Value"]`

Comment: If you prefer `"vad_val" => "001"` instead of `:vad_val => "001"` then just remove the `#to_sym` method.

Comment: Ok. In my current file which I shared  I have only this three types , but I might have other types based on payload response  like, number, bool and symbol. in this circumstance I believe I need to only add like below v.class == Hash && %w(String TrueClass Fixnum number bool).include?((v["Type"] || ''))

Comment: hi, yes, exactly. You can add additional classes.  Watch that the case matches (will it be "Number" or "number"?) or you can modify the line to be case insensitive like this... `if v.class == Hash && %w(string trueclass fixnum number bool).include?(v["Type"].to_s.downcase)`

Comment: one more thing which I would like to highlight here is payload response with duplicate key(decision).in c++ we do have multimap to sort out this kind of issue, but I don't think so ruby also support the same. How to achieve the same in current context where my payload response  contains duplicate key.

Comment: How would you like to handle that?  Do you want to provide an array of values?  `:vad_val => ["001", "003"]` ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like this as same key is being used in diff-2 context  in payload response. in current implementation I am going to skip those places where keys are getting repeated.

Comment: So you need a context wrapper?  `{context1: {vad_val: "001", enabled: false}, context2: {vad_val: "003", enabled: true}}`?  You could look at modifying the method to provide that. Anyway, I'll leave you to get on. Good luck.

Comment: what I mean to say it shouldn't skip the duplicate key instead of this it should proceed further. below is the right payload  response which is expected..{:vad_val=>"0001", :enabled=>false, :reg_id=>nil, :buffer_value=>10, :direct=>"From", :direct_val=>"From", :decision=>"From", :Decision=>"From Network",:decision=>"ToTransport" :number=>0, :connections=>nil, :threads=>4, :updates=>nil, :severity=>3, :levelval=>3, :facility=>3, :depend=>""}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74509/discussion-between-user2907032-and-steveturczyn).

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are wanting the end value to look like.  But you will iterate over the hash to generate whatever values you want.

```
filtered_parsed = parsed.select {|k,v| v.is_a? String}
```

That would select only the elements where the value is a string.  Hope that gets you in the right direction.  Check out Enumerable in ruby library for more options.

Comment: I am looking not only for string but Trueclass and fixnum as well. as hash and array  won't return the any meaningful value, so recursively I need to look into again for value. if you see the payload response , then you can understand that under properties section depend  , enabled and facility is  having types string , TrueClass and fixnum so I want to read those as a key and their corresponding value as "", false  and 3 . I hope it clarifies your doubt.